# Run tests in a bazel project in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bazel, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I've created a Bazel project in Intellij according to the wiki provided by my company. I am theoretically supposed to be able to run the java unit tests directly from Intellij now, by clicking the test method and selecting "Run 'Bazel test ...." However, I am not seeing this option, and was wondering if something is missing. I did notice a difference between my project (has the .ijwb extension) and a different team member's project (has a .project extension) and am wondering if this could be related. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://ij.bazel.build/

Answer (score 0):

1. The test targets need to be defined in your project file. Be sure its the case **Bazel** > **Project** > **Open all project view files**
2. Then, the action appears after you sync the IntelliJ project **Bazel** >  **Sync** > **Sync project with BUILD files**

Before it is synced, I believe you can still run the test, but from the build file, not from the Java class.